# Browser extension to hide all the activities of a given user on Stack Exchange

Tags: chrome, stack-exchange

I am looking for a browser extension (preferably Chrome) that can hide all the activities (namely questions, answers and comments) of a given user on Stack Exchange, just like when blocking someone on Facebook will hide most of their activities.

Comment: I'm maybe so curious, but this is not Facebook, so almost everything that people posts here, evenly seemingly to be harsh or criticize on you, will foremost have the willing to contribute to the conversation. Why blocking them be necessary? You can always ignore them, right?

Comment: @Ooker It clutters the notification feed :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I went ahead and wrote a solution for this:

### [StackIgnore](https://github.com/Undo1/StackIgnore)

To install, download [this file](http://github.com/Undo1/StackIgnore/raw/master/stackignore.user.js) and go to `chrome://extensions` (I'm not sure how to do it in other browsers). Check the 'developer mode' checkbox, and then just drag the file onto the window. It should install automagically.

It's very much a work in progress (and can't hide questions yet), but it works wonders for answers & comments. Here's how it works:

It adds an item in the sidebar on the homepage:

> [image]

Clicking the link under 'Ignored users' brings up a text field. In that field you type the user ID of the person you want to silence, then hit go. If you decide that you want to unsilence them, you do this again to remove them from the list. This is probably the most counterintuitive aspect, and could be improved.

Once you've ignored someone, their answers and comments will magically disappear. When it's hiding answers, it adds this to the answer header:

> [image]

And shows a box at the bottom of the question-answer set, right before the add answer box, with the option to show the answers again:

> [image]

Clicking the link shows the hidden answers with a light blue tint. The same thing is done for comments.

As I said, it's a work in progress. The project is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Undo1/stackignore), please feel free to fork and make any improvements you wish!